# Delete all rows except the results from a given query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-delete

I have two models A and B and a relation table ab.

This query shows all valid entries in the relation table

```
select *
from ab
join a on (ab.a=a.id)
join b on (ab.b=b.id)
where a.pid=b.pid
```

How can I delete all invalid entries, so all except the ones found with the above query?

Comment: Are you trying to delete the invalid rows from the table `ab`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
delete from a
where id not in
(
    select * from 
    (
      select a.id
      from ab
      join a on (ab.a=a.id)
      join b on (ab.b=b.id)
      where a.pid=b.pid
    ) x
);

delete from b
where id not in
(
    select * from 
    (
      select b.id
      from ab
      join a on (ab.a=a.id)  
      join b on (ab.b=b.id)
      where a.pid=b.pid
    ) x
);

delete ab from ab
left join a on ab.a = a.id
left join b on ab.b = b.id
where a.pid <> b.pid
or a.id is null 
or b.id is null;
```

### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/664857)

Comment: Now table `a` and `b` are cleaned, but there could remain invalid entries in the `ab` table. Would you add that to your answer?

Comment: I added the `ab` cleanup.

Comment: your `ab` cleanup does not respect the condition that a.pid has to match b.pid in my query. I still have entries where both is not null but their pid does not match

Comment: The first two queries would not work in MySQL - You can't specify the target table in the FROM Clause. You would need to put the results of the query into a temp table, then refer to that in the delete statements.

Comment: @GarethD: You can also use another subselect to make it work when refering to the same table.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by another subselect? The queries you have posted do not work as far as I can tell - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fd136

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to remove the invalid relations, possibly using a pair of LEFT JOINs in a DELETE:-

```
DELETE ab
FROM ab
LEFT OUTER JOIN a ON ab.a = a.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN b ON ab.b = b.id
WHERE a.id IS NULL
OR b.id IS NULL
```

If you need to clean the other 2 tables up as well then the following 2 queries should do it:-

```
DELETE a
FROM a
LEFT OUTER JOIN ab ON a.id = ab.a
WHERE ab.a IS NULL


DELETE b
FROM b
LEFT OUTER JOIN ab ON b.id = ab.b
WHERE ab.b IS NULL
```